# How to ensure Angular app recognizes/loads my scss files?

Tags: angular, sass

I have bootstrap and customs scss in a package in assets/scss/styles.scss.  I have it included in angular.json file, it is even recognized enough to warn me of a division deprecation in the console when I run ng Serve, but the application does not recognize the styles on my components.
-I have tried to fix this for hours and cannot figure it out.  I have tried @import"src/assets/scss/styles.scss" in styles.scss, I have tried everything I can think of and no global scss are being recognized.  I checked and the local scss files ARE working for their respective components.  What can I try?  What might I be doing wrong?  This is a project that I have had the same code for a long time and never had this issue before.

Answer (score 0):

I never did solve this problem, but at least found a way to make it go away on its own "magically".  I was using an older project that was a mishmash of things built with an older angular-cli version and other older packages.
I just made a new app and then pasted my assets folder and copy and pasted one of the components to get the fastest answer I could as to whether it would import the styles.  Voila it did.  No telling what was causing the app to be incapable of registering the styles though.